# What's the Pythonic way of flipping between two values?

Tags: python

EDIT: My original question was a bit unclear, so I have updated it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Suppose I have some different values: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, ..., and some variable `x` that is equal to one of these. Furthermore suppose I know that the opposite of `A` is `B`, the opposite of `C` is `D`, and so on.

What I want is some clean way of mirroring the boolean `x = not x` but for these generic values. Right now all I can think of is a horrible if-else chain:

```
if x == A:
    x = B
elif x == B:
    x = A
elif x == C:
    x = D
elif x == D:
    x = C
elif ...
```

To give some indication of what I'm after, in Haskell I could define this as as:

```
foo :: x -> x
foo A = B
foo B = A
foo C = D
foo D = C
...
```

and then simply call `foo x`.

Comment: If they're numeric, `x = A + B - x`, although that's going to fail miserably if `x` ever gets a value other than the two intended ones.

Comment: @jasonharper How does that work if x is undefined?

Comment: Oh you need to do `x = A` before

Comment: Given the *completely rewritten question*, `x = {A:B, B:A, C:D, D:C}[x]`.  (Ideally, pre-generate that dict rather than creating it anew each time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a dict with 2-way mappings. Something like

```
pairs = [(A, B), (C, D), ...]
d = dict([*pairs, *map(reversed, pairs)])
```

Then `x = d[x]`.

If for whatever reason you don't like the idea of instantiating a full list of the pairs and reversed pairs, you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
d = dict(chain(pairs, map(reversed, pairs)))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is

```py
x = B if x == A else A
```

Answer (score 0):

After editing my question, I came to the realization I can do this:

```
def flip(x):
    if x == A: return B
    if x == B: return A
    if x == C: return D
    if x == D: return C
    ...
```

Still, if anyone knows of a better way, feel free to post an answer.